# ActiveMQ 5.9.0, Glassfish 3.1.2 and MDB for long lasting message processing

Tags: java, glassfish, activemq-classic

I've got a MessageDrivenBean, running in `Glassfish 3.1.2`, listening to an `ActiveMQ 5.9.0 Queue`.
When a Message is processed and needing a long time, other messages wait for processing.

Test scenario: Sending a big message (needing approx. 30 minutes to process) and 250 small messages while the first is still in progress. Then 62 of the small messages wait for the big one before they get processed.

The MessageDrivenBean has a bean-pool size of 4, in this test I did not use a prefetch limit. Additional tests with various settings (e.g. `?jms.prefetchPolicy.queuePrefetch=20` or `...=2`, threadpool max queue size 2) did not solve the problem, there are always small messages waiting for the big one.

My question is: does anybody know a way how to configure the `MDB`, `ActiveMQ` and/or `glassfish` to avoid this problem? Or is this a typical scenario for polling, e.g. by a `TimerBean`? I know, alternatively I could work with two queues and two MDB (one for big and one for smaller messages), but this would mean that some other JMS communication parties would need to be changed.

Thank you in advance and best regards,
Marc

Comment: Looking over the [ActiveMQ documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html) I would expect your approach of limiting the prefetch setting to a small value to work. Since you are still seeing messages in wait, I suspect that there is another setting in play when consuming messages using an MDB. You might want to try to explicitly set an [activation spec](http://activemq.apache.org/activation-spec-properties.html) with a limited number of messages per batch.

Comment: Hello krautmeyer, thanks a lot for your answer. I already tried the activation spec property "maxMessagesPerSessions" with a value of 1, but that did not solve the problem.